# Посчитать количество записей, группируя по логину и по дате

Tags: mysql

уважаемы гуру!

Проблема: есть таблица:

[image]

Как мне составить запрос таким образом чтобы вывелось сколько человек написал сообщений (login) группируя притом по дням (date)

прим.: date - unix timestamp

я с двумя группировками не сталкивался, гуглил, не помогает

```
SELECT  
login
, FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') as dt 
, count(*) as aa
FROM `iq` GROUP BY login order by date
```

как этот результат сгруппировать по дням?

Comment: всем спасибо, такой запрос все сделал: `SELECT  
 login
 , FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') as dt 
    , count(login) as aa
    
    FROM `iq`
GROUP BY dt, login
order by date`

Comment: Сами себе ответьте здесь, чтобы вопрос засчитался отвеченным, а не поднимался в будущем.